# How do I make my JavaScript search Advanced?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently having a Javascript search like this:

```
 <input type="text" id="link-box"/>
<input type="button" id="search-button" value="Search" 
    onclick="window.location = document.getElementById('link-box').value;"/>
```

The Script;

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

  function func(){
       window.location = document.getElementById('link-box').value;
  }

  onclick="func();"
  
</script>
```

What this basically does is that it opens the "value" the user input. (eg; if the user entered 1 it would open "www.example.com/1" ).

What I want to do is I want to add another text field to the search form as such:

```
<input type="text" id="link-box2"/>
```

Now there are two fields and a submit button in my output. What I want is that, I want the 2nd text field to open the link adding a "/" for the user input value in the 1st field. (eg;  previously if the user inputs the value "1" and it opens "www.example.com/1", now with the 2nd text field: if the user input the value "1" in the 1st text field and the value "2" in the 2nd text field, it should open "www.example.com/1/2").
Simply, there should be some relationship between "link-box"(1st text field) and "link-box2" (2nd text field).
Im new to JavaScript, So please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is that you must use your url before the getting value code.

`function func(){ window.location = "https://example.com/"+ document.getElementById('link-box').value; }`

or

`function func(){ var searchKey = document.getElementById('link-box').value; window.location = "https://example.com/"+ searchKey; }`

if you want to add from other input also ... you can do this

```
function func(){
       var searchKey = document.getElementById('link-box').value;
       var searchKey2 = document.getElementById('link-box2').value;
       if(!searchKey2){
       window.location = "https://example.com/"+ searchKey;
       }else{
       window.location = "https://example.com/"+ searchKey + "/" + searchKey2;
       }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, mate, This was really helpful. Baarakallahu Feekum.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try this one.

**HTML:**

```
 <input type="text" id="link-box"/>
 <input type="button" id="search-button" value="Search" onclick="search()"/>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
const search=()=>{
  let search-value = document.getElementById('link-box').value;
  if(!search-value){
     window.location = `https://example.com/${firstInput}`;
}
  return;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// On input button click, call function func();
<input type="button" id="search-button" value="Search" 
    onclick="func()"/>

<script>
function func() {
  // Gets the values of the 2 input fields.
  let firstInput = document.getElementById('link-box1').value;
  let secondInput = document.getElementById('link-box2').value;
  
  // Redirect the user to the specified URL with the values from the input boxes.
  window.location = 'https://example.com/' + firstInput + '/' + secondInput;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, This was really helpful. Baarakaalhu Feekum.